# Interface builder storyboard compiler error when editing the xml file

Tags: iphone, xml, xcode, ipad

I manually add  element in the storyboard file of my iPhone/iPad developement.
In fact, I copy views in storyboard for iPad and I compute the proportional sizes for iPhone (1024x768 to 480x320).
It works correctly but there is an error when adding a  containing several imageviews on it:

```
*CompileStoryboard iboniaIphoneLGT/LGT_iphone.storyboard
    cd /Users/imac/Desktop/WORKSPACE
    setenv IBSC_MINIMUM_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION 5.1
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    setenv XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool 
    --errors 
    --warnings 
    --notices 
    --output-format human-readable-text 
    --compile 
            /Users/imac/Desktop/WORKSPACE/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/LGT.app/LGT_iphone.storyboardc 
            /Users/imac/Desktop/WORKSPACE/iboniaIphoneLGT/LGT_iphone.storyboard 
    --sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk

Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool 
failed with exit code 255*
```

The message is not explicit, what is the possible cause of this message???

Reex

Comment: I'm struggling with the same problem.  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: the image source used by the image views I used don't yet exist in the <resources> section of the storyboard xml file!

Comment: Oh, ok.  My problem was a little different, but ultimately solved!

Comment: I had UIGestureRecognizers that were "attached" to a view that I had removed. Fortunately I knew what page I was working on and just looked for "!" by anything.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error and eventually found that when I selected one of the images used in the xib in the project navigator, it did not have the project checked in the File Inspector under "Target Membership".  Once I checked that, I didn't get the error anymore.

So I would suggest checking all the images and other resources used in the xib and make sure they have their target membership correct.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was caused by adding one equal-width constraint. It does not make sense. I am pretty wary of Xcode by now.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was just to remove some warnings I had. The warnings I changed was just changing var:s to let:s on properties that was not changed on 4 places